# Foil wrap cooking fully assembled burger in George Foreman grill?

Tags: bread, meat, fire, grill, foil-cooking

If I seal a burger, complete with bun, in tin foil, and cook it in a George Foreman grill...

Will the burger cook through without the bread burning?
Will the bread burn or potentially cause a fire?
Will this just fail to properly cook the burger?

Comment: I don't own a GF grill, but I have  sandwich press.  This doesn't sound like an idea that would yield a good result.  ...steamed burger inside a potentially burned bun...   What is the benefit?

Comment: I want the bread to catch all the fat, letting none escape. I tried cooking a burger on a  bun slowly in an oven for this, and that worked, but it is slow.

Previous to that, I would just use a piece of bread as a sponge to consume all the fat, but doing that is... a tedious part of the eating experience, and also basically meant I was eating out of a pot I'd used to cook the burger.

I am not particularly concerned about the burger being steamed. Just about the burger being safely cooked, and the bread still being bread, and not a bunch of carbon.

Oh, and not dying in a house fire.

Comment: If you don't want the fat to escape, couldn't you just take it from the drip tray after cooking and pour it onto the inside surfaces of the bun?

Answer (score 3):

This will not work. You will definitely severely burn the bun well before the patty cooks.

However, a George Forman grill has a catch tray that will capture all the released fat and juices that you could baste onto the bun or patty if you’d like.